# Customer Registration with email address and password only

Tags: magento-1.9, registration

There is a requirement to fast registration process by removing personal information field ( like -First Name and Last Name) from customer registration form and allow to register only by entering email and password.

What will be the effects of removing personal information fields?

Can we recommend such type of changes in Magento?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pure opinion based question. IMO, Magento is highly extendable software and there is no issue if you allow customers with email address and password.

In order to do this, you need to avoid customer attributes such as firstname, lastname from customer registration form and probably you need to disable the validation(model validation) for the same.

Comment: Thank you for your response . if we allow such registration , is there any point where customer can face any error in using our store?

Comment: Yes and no. If you didn't turn off validations on those required attributes (firstname and lastname are required attributes by default),you can expect some errors while they checkout. So in order to avoid it, you need to make those attributes optional and also turn off validations of those fields (from customer model class) and also avoid those attributes from other customer forms too.